# Find the streamline equation of a velocity field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Assume the velocity field:
$$
v_x=-Ue^{-at}\cos \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)\sin \left( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right)
$$
$$
v_y=-Ue^{-at}\sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)\cos \left( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right)
$$

The **streamline equation** is the solution of the differential equation:
$$
ds=\frac{dx}{v_x}=\frac{dy}{v_y}
$$
$$
\iff -Ue^{-at}\sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)\cos \left( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right) dx=-Ue^{-at}\sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)\cos \left( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right)dy
$$
$$ \Rightarrow \tan \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)dx=\tan \left( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right)dy
$$

indefinite integration and adjusting of the constant gives:
$$
\left| \cos \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)\right|=c \cdot \left|\cos \left( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right)\right|
$$
$$
 \iff \cos^2 \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)+\lambda \cdot \cos^2 \left( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right)=0
$$

Given that we are given no initial point $(x_0,y_0)$ to determine $c$, how can a final result be obtained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assume a point on streamline is given which then will be treated a paramter $(x_0,y_0)$ in your equation. Take definite integral from a given point $(x_0,y_0)$ where the streamline passes through, to some arbitrary point $(x,y)$. The integral equation becomes

\begin{equation}
\int_{x_0}^x \tan \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right) \mathrm{d} x  = \int_{y_0}^y \tan \left( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right) \mathrm{d} y
\end{equation}

which gives

\begin{equation}
   - \frac{L}{\pi} \left[ \ln \left|  \cos( \frac{\pi x}{L} ) \right| \right]_{x_0}^x =    - \frac{L}{\pi}  \left[ \ln \left|  \cos( \frac{\pi y}{L} )  \right| \right]_{y_0}^y 
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
   \ln\left| \frac{\cos( \frac{\pi x}{L} )}{\cos( \frac{\pi x_0}{L} )} \right| = \ln\left| \frac{\cos( \frac{\pi y}{L} )}{\cos( \frac{\pi y_0}{L} )} \right|
\end{equation}

Thus the streamline curve $f(x,y) = 0$ that passes through a *given* point $(x_0,y_0)$ is

\begin{equation}
 f(x,y) = \left( \frac{ \cos( \frac{\pi x}{L} )}{ \cos( \frac{\pi y}{L} )} \right)^2 - \underbrace{ \left( \frac{\cos( \frac{\pi x_0}{L} ) }{\cos( \frac{\pi y_0}{L} )}\right)^2}_{c^2} = 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Isn't it more appropriate to square the absolutes (just to get rid of the cases)?

Comment: You are right, I'll edit the answer with squares to be similar to your derivation.